# Does emplace_back construct an object in its new location instead of using a move?

Tags: c++11

From [this](https://abseil.io/tips/112) link it states

> For example, in the code that we began with, my_vec.push_back("foo")
> constructs a temporary string from the string literal, and then moves
> that string into the container, whereas my_vec.emplace_back("foo")
> just constructs the string directly in the container, avoiding the
> extra move. For more expensive types, this may be a reason to use
> emplace_back() instead of push_back(), despite the readability and
> safety costs, but then again it may not. Very often the performance
> difference just won’t matter

So I decided to try that and this is what i did

```
class foo
{
    public:
    int counter;
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Regular constructor\n";
    }
    foo(const foo& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
    }
    foo(foo&& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<foo> f;
   f.push_back(foo()); //Regular constructor and Move Constructor
   f.emplace_back(foo()); //Regular constructor and Move Constructor
}
```

I noticed that both `push_back` and `emplace_back` behave similarly. I was thinking that `emplace_back` will only be calling the regular constructor based on what I read since it will be constructed in the vector stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector::emplace_back(Args&&...)` takes the arguments of the constructor you want to construct your new object with. In your quoted example this is `const char*` for the constructor `string::string(const char*)`. In your own code you're forcing the move constructor by passing a temporary object. To default-construct your object in-place use `f.emplace_back()` without any arguments as the default constructor takes none.

Also to avoid reallocation (potentially more moves that would spoil your test) ensure the vector has space for your two test objects first using `f.reserve(2)`.

Full code:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor\n";
    }
    foo(const foo& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
    }
    foo(foo&& f)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<foo> f;
   f.reserve(2);
   f.push_back(foo());
   f.emplace_back();
}
```

Output is

```
Default constructor
Move constructor
Default constructor
```

Comment: thanks for clearing this up. I did not know that emplace_back allows default construction